# How do I make my own header file in C?

Tags: c, file, header, wget

I tried to make my own header file but it doesn't work `vim` says

```
wget.h:2:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #ifndef__WGET_H__
wget.h:3:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #define__WGET_H__
wget.h:7:2: error: #endif without #if
```

My code is this:

```
//wget header file
#ifndef__WGET_H__
#define__WGET_H__

int my_wget (char web_address[]);

#endif /*__WGET_H__*/
```

it seems fine to me (the examples I have read are much alike with mine) and I don't know what went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You need a space between the token (e.g. `#ifndef`) and the name of the symbol you're defining/checking.

Comment: You're missing a space as others have pointed out, but please also change the symbol from `__WGET_H__` to `WGET_H_`. Double underscores anywhere within an identifier, or an identifier starting with an underscore followed by uppercase character are reserved by the implementation. Your symbol is violating both those rules.

Comment: @Praetorian "Double underscores anywhere within an identifier" -- true of C++ but not of C. In C, "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right , just the space was missing.

```
#ifndef __WGET_H__
#define __WGET_H__

int my_wget (char web_address[]);

#endif __WGET_H__
```

You would generally use the above , in header files , because , in your project , if you happen(by accident) to include the same header  multiple times , then writing the header like this will make sure  , that it includes the header only once.

Comment: It's not about accidents. If a.h and b.h both include c.h, then including both a.h and b.h in the same file will include c.h twice. This is an extremely common occurrence in real project code. (In fact, it occurs even in single-file programs because system header files often include other system header files.)

Comment: @JimBalter , yes i fully agree with you , but sometimes i happen to do it more as an accident

Answer (score 2):

You must leave a space between the preprocessor keyword and the label:

```
#ifndef __WGET_H__
#define __WGET_H__
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
#ifndef__WGET_H__
#define__WGET_H__
```

to

```
#ifndef __WGET_H__
#define __WGET_H__
```

(note the space between `#ifndef` and `__WGET_H__`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave a space between a preprocessor keyword (e.g. `#define`) and the label (i.e. `__WGET_H__`). In other words:

```
#ifndef __WGET_H__
#define __WGET_H__
```

will work.